# How to see the value of rails environment variables on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production-environment, ubuntu-14.04

I'm currently trying to troubleshoot an issue on a production server for a rails app and have realised I don't know how to view the values of certain environment variables being used by the application.

I'm using figaro to store things such as the devise secret key but need to make sure that the value is correct for the instance of my app that is running.

I'm looking for something along the lines of

```
echo $MY_DEVISE_KEY
```

I understand that I can access figaro's variables from inside the rails console but would that be a different instance?

Also, I'm using ubuntu server and nginx to serve my app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
printenv
```

and you can search for a specific env variable like

```
printenv | grep foo
```

Comment: Though this is a very cool command that I din't know about, unfortunately, it doesn't seem to expose the variables set by Figaro

Comment: I think figaro stores those in a yml file. check config/environments/production.rb on the production box and see if they are there

Comment: yeah it does, I have to manually(ish) update the `.yml` file on the server whenever I change it locally. I just wondered if there was a way to ensure that everything was as expected after a reboot for instance.